# How to call a nested fetch?

Tags: typescript, post, get, fetch

I have a code like the following which works:

```
const url = "https://something";
let data2 = JSON.stringify({ source: "https://someimage.jpg" });
const test1 = fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "mykey",
  },
  body: data2,
}).then((res) =>
  console.log("postHeaderResult" + res.headers.get("Operation-Location"))
);
```

Now, what I want to do is using the `Operation-Location` header which is a `url` address and send a `GET` request and then get the final answer from the body of this new requet.

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
const url = "https://something";
let data2 = JSON.stringify({ source: "https://someimage.jpg" });
const test1 = fetch(url_to_formRecognizer, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "mykey",
  },
  body: data2,
})
  .then((res) =>
    console.log("postHeaderResult" + res.headers.get("Operation-Location"))
  )
  .then((res1) =>
    fetch(test1.headers.get("Operation-Location"), {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "34dd609bcb5742de91e8474f0e27e88e",
      },
    }).then((res1) => console.log("finalResult" + res1 + "simple"))
  );
```

In the meantime, if I try my code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), I get an error on `test1`, but in my `visual studio` I don't get any compilation error though the get request is not performed.
I even tried the following line:

```
.catch((err) => console.log("odsPolicyRequestError" + err));
```

to capture the error but it is also empty. I don't understand what the problem is and what I have done wrong.

Your help would be appreciated.

Update 1:

here is my new code based on the answer. But, I finally get "not started yet" as the result of my second call. It seems that the second call starts before the first one is really finished.

```
 const url = "https://something";
let data2 = JSON.stringify({ source: documentUrl });
const res1 = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': apiKey},
    body: data2
});
if (!res1.ok) {
  console.log("postHeaderResult not okay first fetch" +  res1.status + " on first fetch");

}
console.log("header is:" + res1.headers.get("Operation-Location"), null);

const res2 = await  fetch(res1.headers.get("Operation-Location"), {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : apiKey }
}).then( res2 => { return res2.text(); }).then(text => { api.output("text" + text, null); } );
```

Comment: Your debugging fulfillment handler is interfering, replacing the fulfillment value from `fetch` with `undefined` (the return value of `console.log`).

Comment: try to use async/await. . it will be much cleaner and readable 
and then  it will be easier to debug 
read about it its easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not too far off, but:

1. Your debugging fulfillment handler is interfering, replacing the fulfillment value from `fetch` with `undefined` (the return value of `console.log`). You'll want to remove it.
2. Don't use the `test1` variable. The fulfillment value is provided to the fulfillment handler (your callback passed to `.then`). That's what you want to use.

Something like this:

```
const url = "https://something";
let data2 = JSON.stringify({ source: 'https://someimage.jpg'});
fetch(url_to_formRecognizer, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'mykey'},
    body: data2
}).then(res1 => fetch(res1.headers.get("Operation-Location"), {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : '34dd609bcb5742de91e8474f0e27e88e' }})
).then(res2 => {
    console.log("finalResult" + res2 + "simple");
});
```

But note that that doesn't consume the body of either the first response or the second one. It looks like you may not need the body of the first one, but I'm guessing you need the body of the second one at least.

Or, if you can use an `async` function, this code (in an `async` function) could use `await` instead of `.then`:

```
const url = "https://something";
let data2 = JSON.stringify({ source: 'https://someimage.jpg'});
const res1 = await fetch(url_to_formRecognizer, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'mykey'},
    body: data2
});
if (!res1.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + res1.status + " on first fetch");
}
const res2 = await fetch(res1.headers.get("Operation-Location"), {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : '34dd609bcb5742de91e8474f0e27e88e' }
});
if (!res2.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + res2.status + " on second fetch");
}
console.log("finalResult" + res2 + "simple");
```

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to a bit of a footgun in the `fetch` API (I write about it [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)). `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* error, not HTTP error. You need to check that things worked at the HTTP level explicitly. Here's how you might do that:

```
const url = "https://something";
let data2 = JSON.stringify({ source: 'https://someimage.jpg'});
fetch(url_to_formRecognizer, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'mykey'},
    body: data2
}).then(res1 => {
    if (!res1.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res1.status + " on first fetch");
    }
    return fetch(res1.headers.get("Operation-Location"), {
         method: "GET",
         headers: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : '34dd609bcb5742de91e8474f0e27e88e' }
    });
}).then(res2 => {
    if (!res2.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res2.status + " on second fetch");
    }
    console.log("finalResult" + res2 + "simple");
});
```

(Or use a `fetch` wrapper that does the `ok` check for you, as I describe in that linked blog post.)

---

Side note 2: It's important to always either handle promise rejection (in this case, probably with a `.catch` at the end) or pass the promise chain back to the caller so the caller can check for it. Your code doesn't appear to do either.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer and sorry if I have asked (and still ask) stupid quetsions. It's just 2-3 weeks I have started programming with typescript. Could you please tell me how I can get the body of the res2? I have tried `res2.status` and it is ok and 200 which means everything seems to be fine, but none of  `res2.text`, `res2`, and `res2.body` return the response that I expect. I just get objects or texts which are irrelevant.

Comment: @user13578 - No worries! You *read* the body by using one of the methods on the response object that does that, [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch). For instance, if you want it as text, you'd call the [`text` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) and wait for the promise it returns to fulfill.

Comment: But when I use text(), I get `text() {
return consumeBody.call(this).then(function (buffer) {
return buffer.toString();
});
}`

Comment: @user13578 - As I said above, you need to wait for the promise to fulfill. E.g.: `.then(res2 => { if (!res2.ok) { throw new Error(/*...*/); } return res2.text(); }).then(text => { /* use the text here */ })`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Now, I get another error. Could you please see Update 1 on my question?

Comment: @user13578 - I suggest stepping back from your current task and studying how promises work, and how promise callbacks work. Also, don't mix `await` with `.then`. Use one or the other. See the answer above for how to use each of them. FWIW, I go into promises in detail in Chapter 8 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*, and I go into `async`/`await` in detail in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested. :-)